# how to draw the shape of rectangle whose one side is crossed in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need a rectangle whose one side should be crossed or cut like the image shown.

[image: I need the same result like below image]

What I have tried so far:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">; 
    <!-- This is the line --> 
    <item android:bottom="2dp" > 
       <shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:shape="rectangle" > 
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" /> 
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
        </shape> 
     </item> 
  </layer-list>
```

it just round the corner... i need only one corner should bhe cutted like image shown

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Nobody is just going to give your the solution, that is not what stack overflow is for.

Comment: I have triend this .<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the line -->

    <item  android:bottom="2dp" >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
                android:topRightRadius="8dp" /></shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: it just round the corner... i need only one corner should bhe cutted like image shown

Comment: I've added your statements to your question. Those belong in the question and not in comments. Please provide essential details like that in the future in your question. Basically we always want to see code.

Answer (score -1):

Just draw two rectangles and one triangle for the background.[image]

It's really that simple.

Comment: isn't better just to draw a Path (drawPath) with such a shape?

Comment: Not perse. If you look in graphics calls these are 5 triangles to fill in for which graphics processor is optimised to do. If you draw a custom path it has to draw the path, calculate poligons from path then fill them in. There is a gpu overhead in there. Which isnt noticable if you have one element, but what if you have 50 elements and some animations. on low end phones you might lose some interactivity and have some lag.